# Swipe to delete not working while on edit mode

Tags: ios, uitableview, swipe

I'm having the following problem.

I have an app using a UITableView with a custom UITableViewCell. Because of the specs of the app, I need it to be in edit mode **always**, so on the viewDidLoad I wrote this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    MainTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"compose_background.png"]];
    [MainTableView setAllowsSelectionDuringEditing: TRUE];
    [MainTableView setEditing: TRUE];

    [super viewDidLoad];    
}
```

Also, I've implemented the following methods:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And several more, but the problem persists and when I swipe a cell the delete button doesn't shows up. Any pointers would be highly appretiated.

Comment: while I can handle criticism well, I think that downvoting a question that has taken some time to ask, and that I've done some digging about it without saying why is just plain cruel.

Comment: Upped it back to zero (I didn't down it). But don't worry about criticism from strangers. It's not a bad question if you're not a pro.

Comment: thanks psoft! I actually think that criticism is a good thing but only when properly justified! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` must return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` for each row you want to delete. Swipe-to-delete is disabled in favor of this method when in editing mode.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks for the heads up, I think that will have to go with Ell's idea

Comment: Yep, I think that's the only way. I think you could implement the swipe gesture on the actual cell... let us know what works for you!

Comment: Keep in mind, though, that implementing swipe-to-delete while in edit mode is a bit of a contradiction of Apple's standards, and, if that contradiction is apparent in the UI, your app might be rejected. Let us know what works for you!

Comment: @QED I know this is old, but could you be more precise, where is that contradiction defined?

Comment: I'm not sure that I can point you to any specific documentation on the subject. In edit mode, there are UX controls for deleting/adding/etc based on editingStyle... and those controls are fundamentally different than those displayed in swipe-to-delete. So I guess that's the contradiction. Read up on editing table views

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anyway for the standard swipe to delete to work while the table view is in editing mode, you'd have to respond to gestures and add your own delete button.